# Reset old Hostname in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, networking, mac, dns, hostname

Everytime I change the Hostname of my mac it starts to work but doesn't forget the old Hostname. For example:

- hostname: example.com
- ping example.com - it points to my computer
- so, I change hostname to example.local
- ping example.com - it still points to my computer

What is wrong?

I've tried to flush DNS, change using command changeip, use the server.app for OS X Lion, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Classic culprits are `/etc/hosts` and your DHCP server. Worth double-checking those.

Comment: are you pinging from your mac to yourself? or from a different computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under **System Preferences > Network > Advanced > DNS**, DNS Servers were set to 127.0.0.1. Strangely it was the problem.

I solved this just removing it clicking on **-** at the bottom of the list. Automatically it set to the right DNS Server.